# How to get HTMLElement ID if it includes a "-"

Tags: c#, html, variables, naming-conventions

I am trying to load Google and get the ID of the searchbox. The ID of the box is "lst-ib". Which when the program goes to debug it is expecting a semicolon.

Is there a way around it to get the element id? So far I have:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Process.Start("www.google.com");

            HtmlElement lst-ib = WebBrowser1.Document.All["foo"];
            //expects a semi colon on the line above after the element id

            if (lst-ib != null)
            {
                lst-ib.InnerText = "test";
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Erm so don't use a variable with the same name, i.e use `HtmlElement lst_ib` - You can name it whatever you like (so long as it obeys the naming rules)

Answer (score 1):

That is C# code and `-` is not valid in identifiers. Feel free to name the variable as you wish – it has no bearing on what the ID of the element is.

Answer (score 1):

The  **-**  is an ***operator***, you cannot use this way!

Here you will find more information about operators:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

I recomend you rename - (trace) to _ (underline) or anyway you want

=D